# SQL issue with a function

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MSG_FilterAutoship]
(
    @ItemID VARCHAR(50) = NULL
)
RETURNS 
@Autoship TABLE 
(
    DistID INT,
    BusCtrID INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Autoship (DistID, BusCtrID)
        SELECT [as].Distid, 1 as busctrid
        FROM Autoship [as]
        INNER JOIN AutoshipDetail ad ON [as].DistID = ad.DistID
        INNER JOIN AS_DistributorCreditCard acc ON [as].DistID = acc.DistID
        WHERE [ad].InventoryID IN (@ItemID)
    RETURN 
END
```

What I need to have happen is if @ItemID is passed in a null value, then `WHERE [ad].InventoryID IN (@ItemID)` would basically not filter the results at all.  Is this possible?

So basically if I pass in 120, 520 it would filters the results so only those two items are shown.  If I pass in NULL then it would show all items.

Split function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @Delimiter CHAR,
    @Text TEXT
)
RETURNS @Result TABLE (RowID SMALLINT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, Data VARCHAR(MAX))
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @NextPos INT,
        @LastPos INT

    SELECT  @NextPos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Text, 1),
        @LastPos = 0

    WHILE @NextPos > 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT  @Result
                (
                    Data
                )
            SELECT  SUBSTRING(@Text, @LastPos + 1, @NextPos - @LastPos - 1)

            SELECT  @LastPos = @NextPos,
                @NextPos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Text, @NextPos + 1)
        END

    IF @NextPos <= @LastPos
        INSERT  @Result
            (
                Data
            )
        SELECT  SUBSTRING(@Text, @LastPos + 1, DATALENGTH(@Text) - @LastPos)

    RETURN
END
```

Here is the updated query that uses the split function:

```
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Autoship (DistID, BusCtrID)
        SELECT [as].Distid, 1 as busctrid
        FROM Autoship [as]
        INNER JOIN AutoshipDetail ad ON [as].DistID = ad.DistID
        INNER JOIN AS_DistributorCreditCard acc ON [as].DistID = acc.DistID
        WHERE [ad].InventoryID IN (SELECT Data from dbo.Split(',', @ItemID)) or @ItemID IS NULL 
    RETURN 
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  `WHERE InventoryID = @ItemID OR @ItemID IS NULL`.  Note that TSQL will not automatically expand "1, 2, 3" into "IN (1, 2, 3)", rather it will compare InventoryID to "1, 2, 3" and presumably come up with no matches.

Comment: this worked as far as I can tell, but I do not understand how it worked.  I have a split function if they pass in 1,2,3,4,5 etc that allows it to work if they put in more than one itemid.

Comment: Well, it would read as this WHERE InventoryID IN (NULL) OR '@ItemID' IS NULL.  How does it bypass the where in NULL, and '@ItemID' is NULL.  Does the IN clause error out, and since the or statement is true it processes the sql?  I'm thankful it works, just wish I understood why it worked better.

Comment: The expression `WHERE ID IN (NULL) OR @ItemID IS NULL` returns true, because `ID IN (NULL)` is false but `@ItemID IS NULL` is true.  The `IN` clause does not produce an error, it just says "nope, not a match".

Comment: Note that while `ID IN (NULL)` simply returns false, depending on your implementation your split function could error out when fed a NULL value.  I could give you a better answer with the actual query; your code above is leaving out the split, which is important.

Comment: Alright that helps me understand it, thank you for the solution @Jonofalltrades will post the function above in an edit.

Comment: I added the function and the updated sql that uses the split function at the bottom.

Comment: I tested it with the split function and it seemed to work just fine, tried it with a single item id, multiple item id's and null.  Thank you again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just add it to your Where clause:

```
WHERE @ItemID IS NULL OR [ad].InventoryID IN (@ItemID)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return all rows if NULL is passed else return only the records that are in itemid

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MSG_FilterAutoship]
(
    @ItemID VARCHAR(50) = NULL
)
RETURNS 
@Autoship TABLE 
(
    DistID INT,
    BusCtrID INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Autoship (DistID, BusCtrID)
        SELECT [as].Distid, 1 as busctrid
        FROM Autoship [as]
        INNER JOIN AutoshipDetail ad ON [as].DistID = ad.DistID
        INNER JOIN AS_DistributorCreditCard acc ON [as].DistID = acc.DistID
        WHERE [ad].InventoryID IN (@ItemID) or [ad].InventoryID IS NULL
    RETURN 
END
```